How to handle huge object data structure on Typescript
I have this code:
let rawResult: string = ...; //Get from API
let result: any = JSON.parse(rawResult);

Basically the return from an API is a big object when parsed. More than 10 properties and some properties are nested arrays and objects.
Example:
{
  "status": 200,
  "messages": [],
  "description": "Lorem Ipsum",
  "colors": ["red",v"white",v"pink"
  ],
  "data": [
    [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ],
    [ 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 ],
    [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ],
    [ 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 ]
  ]
}

Right now, I'm using any and works fine. But I'm wondering what would be the best practice in this situation.

Best practice in what sense?

Create a type or interface that describes the object returned by your API. Either will work but you might want to choose one over the other depending on your use case. A quick google search brought me here which might be able to do the conversion for you. Just make sure you edit out any sensitive information first

U have to use fetch with interface

"more than ten properties" is still well within the realm of interfaces people write.  Nested properties are also fine. Right now this feels like an opinion question since the example is vague and "best practice" isn't quite objective here. Could you [edit] to give some objective criteria for deciding what a best practice is, and hopefully a [mre] of an example that doesn't have any typos in it? (what's v)?

And if you really can't write the interface by hand, tools like quicktype can do it automatically for you.

If you know all fields receiving object then create interface/class/type, and use object.fieldName syntax.
Else use object['fieldName'] syntax with any type
